# Change secondary email address on Google account

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a Google Account where the primary email is a non-Gmail address. By accident, I added a (silly) Gmail address to this account. Now I would like to delete the silly Gmail address and replace it with a sensible one.  I do not wish to lose this Google Account as it has many things I need to keep. So the question is: If I delete the silly Gmail name, will I lose the account?

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer

Go to http://myaccount.google.com and Remove Gmail permanently. This will remove Gmail address as the primary email address of your account and later will allow you to choose another Gmail address, if you like to do so.

## Remarks

- Once a Gmail address is added to a Google Account, it becomes the primary email address for that account.
- Acording to [Sign in to your Google Account with another email address - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en) Gmail addresses can't be used as alternate email addresses.

## How to

From [Cancelling your Gmail address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177?hl=en)

> Delete your Gmail address
>
> 1. Sign in to My Account.
> 2. In the “Account preferences” section, select Delete your account or services.
> 3. Choose Delete products.
> 4. In the “Delete a Product” section, select Remove Gmail permanently.
> 5. Follow the onscreen instructions and select Remove Gmail.

Comment: Thank you. I am quite clear that the primary email address for this account is a non-gmail address. The gmail address which  I associated with the account (by accident) is not the primary, so is it the alternate?  But my main concern is to be quite sure that I won't delete the whole account if I delete the gmail address.

Comment: @Susan a Gmail mail address can't be the alternate email address for a Google Account but it could be "associated" in several ways for differents purposes. I.E. You can sign in to multiple accounts at once or you could add to a contact record for yourself several email addresses. Which steps did you followed to associate your email addresses? How do you know that they are associated?

Comment: @Rubén :  On the settings/email page I can see that my non-gmail address is the primary and the silly gmail address is listed as 'other'. Does this mean that I actually have 2 separate accounts?

Comment: @Susan add a screenshot to your question. In order to protect your privacy before uploading the image mask the username of your email addresses but left the domain visible.(i.e. for email addresses should be visible XXX@gmail.com, XXX@yahoo.com, etc)

Answer (score -1):

Depends, if its the "main" email of the account it's impossible
but if you mean the "backup" email I'm sure you can reverse the progress shown [HERE](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en).